# Python SpeechRecognition not giving response

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, raspberry-pi-zero

SpeechRecognition is not giving a response if I use a live microphone.

I have successfully installed the SpeechRecognition library and PyAudio using python3 -m pip install ...
I am working on a Raspberry Pi Zero in a virtual environment with:
Python 3.7.3
pip 21.0.1

I am using the Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone Breakout and am able to successfully record using:

```
arecord -D plughw:1 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v file.wav
```

When I save this in a file (file.wav) and use the following code, the speech recognizer works:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('file.wav') as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

try:
        print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknowValueError:
        print("Sorry, could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

But when I want to do live speech recognition with the following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(1) as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

try:
        print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknowValueError:
        print("Sorry, could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

It gives the following output and keeps saying: 'Say something' without showing any transcript:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib conf.c:5014:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters {AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Say something!
```

When I press ^C after a while because nothing is happening the following bit is added:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "srwm.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/pythonyt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 620, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/pythonyt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/pythonyt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.
I hope there is someone really smart that can help me, thanks in advance!

New code after first answer:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(1) as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

data = ""
try:
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said: " + data)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sorry, could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

return data
```

Giving error that return is outside function.

Comment: try to put   r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) just below the with statement may be it can work!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the part which translates the speech to text...Try this:

```
data = ""
try:
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said: " + data)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sorry, could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

return data
```

This is the whole code that would work I guess:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def Recognize():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(1) as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    data = ""
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry, could not understand audio")
        print(e)

    return data 

if __name__=="__main__":
    data = Recognize().lower()
    print(data)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I have tried it but get the error that return is outside function. When adding a tab it says inconsistent use of tabs. Please see my code.

Comment: Well you need to keep the whole process of recognition in a function.

Comment: Sorry I am really a beginner in python. Can you please explain where I should put the return statement?

Comment: I updated my answer...check it and you will understand :)

Comment: Thank you so much I am going to try it!

Comment: Mmmm it is not giving any output when I run it.

Comment: Thanks, gives output now but still keeps showing 'Say something' even though I am screaming in the mic :)

Comment: Hmm..it will happen because it would take some time before doing the Recognizing process....it can also happen if your connection is slow

Comment: I let it run for a couple of minutes but unfortunately no response.

Comment: Hmm...I would suggest you to check this link...https://codewithharry.com/videos/python-tutorials-for-absolute-beginners-120

Comment: Let me know if it works...well you can try the one which I have edited.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing...but did it worked??

Comment: I would be really very Happy to help you :)

Comment: that is good to hear, it still keeps showing say something. Now I have changed r.listen to r.record(source, duration=5). This gives error: AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'UnknowValueError'

Comment: Just tested unfortunately still not working... I have the idea that the problem is with the mic waiting for a specific threshold of sound to record. I am going to look into it.